# Does an ASUS pa* series display work with Ubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, monitor, compatibility, asus

I'm thinking of purchasing an ASUS PA246Q 24" monitor but it has a bunch of extra features which I don't know if it will work with Ubuntu. I can't find any details on system requirements or any of that kind of information so I guess it is all done inside of the monitor and doesn't use the computer for that kind of stuff.

Can anyone with some experience regarding this help me out? So that I don't buy something I will regret :)

[ASUS PA246Q 24](http://www.asus.com/Display/LCD_Monitors/PA246Q/#specifications)

Comment: What "extra features" are you referring to?

Comment: @Niklas: if you are going to buy this in a (physical) shop, you can ask if they let you connect your laptop to such a monitor to test (doesn't have to be exactly the same, just a model from the same series)?  I think this monitor is probably expensive enough that they will understand you want it to work properly with your software...  :)

Comment: Good idea! There is a store relatively close to me that I might take a trip to and test this, though my original plan was to order it online. But it's without a doubt worth going to a store first and see if it works as it should :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB, color manage management, etc, will work out of the box, they are hardware / monitor dependent. Quick Fit seems to be built in to the monitor's firmware and wont depend on external software.

The automatic rotate screen feature will not work out of the box but with some small adjustments you can make you desktop rotate with a simple hot key shortcut, that is graphics card dependent but most new GPUs will be able to do that in Ubuntu.

If you are buying a screen like this I really doubt you are using an old graphics card, if that is an interesting feature that you need check if your graphics card is supported and works good in Linux.

Comment: Ok, I can live with that. Thanks! I'll accept this as an answer if no one with experience of using this monitor comes along :)

Comment: sounds fair, gl with your new screen, looks very good!

Comment: QuickFit seems to be implemented in the monitor firmware, not as software on the attached PC, so it should work fine.

Comment: And it's not clear to me how the rotation thing is implemented, but it might work automatically with the xrandr-based monitor setup configuration tool that comes with GNOME (or other DE).  (That requires proper xrandr support in your graphics card drivers though.)

Comment: fair enough, fixed.